Is it acceptable to pass a list of the same aggregate root type to a method in Domain-Driven Design (DDD)
We are learning and implementing Domain-Driven Design (DDD), and we have a sample entity below: PaymentInvoice.
My question is, is it acceptable to pass a list of PaymentInvoice entities to the AllocateAmountPaidToPaymentInvoiceDetails, ValidatePaymentInvoices, and GetPaidPaymentInvoiceDetail  method? Please see the sample code below:
public class PaymentInvoice : AggregateRoot
{ 
    private readonly List<PaymentInvoiceDetail> _paymentInvoiceDetails; 

    public void AllocateAmountPaidToPaymentInvoiceDetails(
        IEnumerable<PaymentInvoice> partiallyPaidPaymentInvoices, 
        Invoice invoice, 
        IEnumerable<LvAmountSubType> amountSubTypes) 
    { 
        ValidatePaymentInvoices(partiallyPaidPaymentInvoices, invoice); 
        var paidPaymentInvoiceDetails = GetPaidPaymentInvoiceDetail(partiallyPaidPaymentInvoices); 
        var orderedInvoiceDetails = GetOrderedInvoiceDetails(invoice, amountSubTypes); 
        var amountRemaining = AmountPaid.Value; 

        foreach (var invoiceDetail in orderedInvoiceDetails) 
        { 
            var balance = CalculateRemainingBalance(invoiceDetail, paidPaymentInvoiceDetails); 
            if (balance <= 0) 
                continue; 
            
            var amountToAllocate = Math.Min(amountRemaining, balance);               
            AddPaymentInvoiceDetail (params...);               
            amountRemaining -= amountToAllocate; 
        } 
    } 

    private void AddPaymentInvoiceDetail(params.....) 
    { 
        var paymentInvoiceDetail = PaymentInvoiceDetail.Create(.....)        
            _paymentInvoiceDetails.Add(paymentInvoiceDetail); 
    } 

    private static void ValidatePaymentInvoices(IEnumerable<PaymentInvoice> paymentInvoices, Invoice invoice) 
    { 
        if (paymentInvoices != null && paymentInvoices.Any(x => !x.InvoiceId.Equals(invoice.Id))) 
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Partially paid invoices must match the given invoice."); 
    } 
    
    private static List<PaymentInvoiceDetail> GetPaidPaymentInvoiceDetail(IEnumerable<PaymentInvoice> paymentInvoices) 
    { 
        return paymentInvoices?.SelectMany(x => x.PaymentInvoiceDetails).ToList() ?? [];
    } 
}

This list of PaymentInvoice entities will only serve as a basis for some logic inside the method, and we are not modifying their state or values.
Most articles we found online suggest passing other aggregate roots, but not of the same type.

Update
Again, kind of the same problem. Your AggregateRoot should already know everything it needs, it should not depend on other AggregateRoots.
I guess the problem in your structure is the partial payments, which should probably be a sub-class to your AggregateRoot (a backing field), which is kind of is? I'm not sure.
Something like:
public class PaymentInvoice : AggregateRoot
{ 
    // partial payments?
    private readonly List<PaymentInvoiceDetail> _paymentInvoiceDetails; 
    public decimal FullAmountToPay { get; private set; } 

    public decimal AllocateAmountPaidToPaymentInvoiceDetails()
    {
        var amountPaid = _paymentInvoiceDetails.Sum(c => c.AmountPayed);
        return FullAmountToPay - amountPaid;
    }

    
    private void AddPaymentInvoiceDetail(decimal amount) 
    { 
        _paymentInvoiceDetails.Add(new PaymentInvoiceDetail(amount)); 
    } 
}

Also, use some constructor validation, that's why constructors were invented. Then you wont have to 'validate this' and 'validate that' later down the line. You should only create the object in a well defined state. (The same goes for all sub classes).
Sample:
public class PaymentInvoice : AggregateRoot
{ 
    public decimal FullAmountToPay { get; private set; } 
    public decimal CreatedAt { get; private set; } 

    public PaymentInvoice(decimal amount)
    {
        if (amount <= 0)
            // just a custom exception
            throw new DomainException("A payment invoice cannot be negative.");

        // probably some other validations in your case

        CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
        FullAmountToPay = amount;
    }
}

Here is a great reference application from Microsoft, microservices with DDD: https://github.com/dotnet/eShop
For instance, look at the OrderItem domain object: https://github.com/dotnet/eShop/blob/main/src/Ordering.Domain/AggregatesModel/OrderAggregate/OrderItem.cs
First answer
To me it sounds a bit weird in logic why you would pass some Payment(s) to another Payment. Maybe you need to diff the payments or something. I don't know the context for that.
The point is that the Payment aggregate root should probably already have all information it needs to update it's internal state, independently of other payments.
public class Payment : IAggregateRoot {

     // note public getter and private setter, should only be accessable to modify from a function in this class instance.
     public List<PaymentDetails> PaymentDetails { get; private set; } 

     void AllocatePayment(List<Payment> otherPayments) {
         // ...         
     }
}

So, in short. Is it acceptable? Sure, why not, if it fits your needs. But to me it sounds a bit funky in logic why you would ever need to do that.

Hi @Henkolicious, I’ve updated my question to provide better context and visualization. I hope this helps.
